# Trying to add persistence to django channel layers, failing to read from Redis

Tags: python, django, database, redis, django-channels

I'm trying to add persistence to django's channel-layers. I am overriding two functions to achieve this: group_add and group_send. Group_send should now store the latest message that it has sent in redis (which it is doing, successfully). Group_add should read this message from redis, and send it each time a new entity joins the group. However, it is failing to read from redis.

```
from channels_redis.core import RedisChannelLayer
from channels.exceptions import ChannelFull
import time

class RedisChannelLayerGroupPersistence(RedisChannelLayer):


    async def group_send(self, group, message):
        """
        Sends a message to the entire group.
        """
        assert self.valid_group_name(group), "Group name not valid"
        # Retrieve list of all channel names
        key = self._group_key(group)
        pers_key = key + bytes("_PERS", 'utf-8')
        async with self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group)) as connection:
            # Discard old channels based on group_expiry
            await connection.zremrangebyscore(key, min=0, max=int(time.time()) - self.group_expiry)
            # Return current lot
            channel_names = [
                x.decode("utf8") for x in
                await connection.zrange(key, 0, -1)
            ]
        # TODO: More efficient implementation (lua script per shard?)  try:
            await connection.persist(pers_key)
            await connection.set(pers_key, str(message))

        for channel in channel_names:
            try:
                await self.send(channel, message)
            except ChannelFull:
                pass

    async def group_add(self, group, channel):

        """
        Adds the channel name to a group.
        """
        # Check the inputs
        assert self.valid_group_name(group), "Group name not valid"
        assert self.valid_channel_name(channel), "Channel name not valid"
        # Get a connection to the right shard
        group_key = self._group_key(group)
        pers_key = group_key + bytes("_PERS", 'utf-8')
        async with self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group)) as connection:
            message = await connection.get(pers_key) #ISSUE HERE MESSAGE NONE
            print(type(message))
            # Add to group sorted set with creation time as timestamp
            await connection.zadd(
                group_key,
                time.time(),
                channel,
            )
            # Set expiration to be group_expiry, since everything in
            # it at this point is guaranteed to expire before that
            try:
                await self.send(channel, eval(message))
            except ChannelFull:
                pass


        await connection.expire(group_key, self.group_expiry)
```

The code is successfully writing the message to redis under the key 'pers_key' - I've confirmed this through the redis cli. Unfortunately, reading (using the `connection.get(pers_key)`, returns none. I have no idea why, as this key definitely exists, and can definitely be accessed (from the redis-cli, at least).

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @zerohedge Yes, replacing the definition of `pers_key` in `group_send` with: `data_key = self._group_key(group + "__DATA__")` worked